# char array not recognized in function

Tags: c, arrays, embedded, string-literals

I'm working on a project for a class.  Embedded C-code.
I'm attempting to create a char array of 5 strings that I declare globally so my LCD function can loop through the list easily.  They could be declared as const but right now I just want it to build without issue.

Problem is I keep getting an 'undeclared' error in the function and 'conflicting types' error pointing at the declaration when I build.  The declaration looks correct but I guess it's not.  What am I missing?
The undeclared error will probably fix itself once the declaration is sorted out.

```
     // Declared before main()
     char _cylinder_types[5];

    _cylinder_types[0] = "Blk";
    _cylinder_types[1] = "Wht";
    _cylinder_types[2] = "Stl";
    _cylinder_types[3] = "Alu";
    _cylinder_types[4] = "Err";
```

inside my lcd.c file:

```
void lcd_display_update(void){

  int i = 0;
  while(i<5)
    {
     lcd_write(0);
     lcd_position(lcd_TopLine,1);
     lcd_string("SORTED:");
     lcd_string(_cylinder_types[i]);
     lcd_write(':');
     lcd_write_Num_8(drop_number[i]);

     lcd_position(lcd_BotLine,1);
     lcd_string("UNSORTED:");
     lcd_string(_cylinder_types[i]);
     lcd_write(':');
     lcd_write_Num_8(queued_number[i]);

     mTimer(5000);
    }
     i++;
}
```

Comment: Show the full code, please. Anyway, you can't assign *strings* to a `char` array elements.

Comment: Given `char _cylinder_types[5];`, just what do you think the `_cylinder_types[0]` array element is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just declare the array like

```
char * _cylinder_types[5];
^^^^^^
```

For example in this expression statement

```
_cylinder_types[0] = "Blk";
```

the string literal `"Blk"` is implicitly converted to an rvalue of the type `char *`.

And you may not place these statements

```
_cylinder_types[0] = "Blk";
_cylinder_types[1] = "Wht";
_cylinder_types[2] = "Stl";
_cylinder_types[3] = "Alu";
_cylinder_types[4] = "Err";
```

outside any function.

You could for example initially initialize the array like

```
 char * _cylinder_types[5] =
 {
     "Blk", "Wht", "Stl", "Alu", "Err"
 };
```

If there are several compilation units in the project then the array should be declared in the header like

```
extern char * _cylinder_types[5];
```

and in some module defined like for example

```
 char * _cylinder_types[5] =
 {
     "Blk", "Wht", "Stl", "Alu", "Err"
 };
```

The header must be included in each module where there is a reference to the array.

Take into account that this statement

```
 i++;
```

shall be inside the while loop.

Comment: @ChefFlambe Check whether the array is declared before the function definition. See also my updated post.

Comment: Thnx, that seemed to fix part of it.  Forgot about the assignment outside function thing.  Nice catch on the i++  Still getting the undeclared (first use in this function) error though.  I've moved all my prototypes after the Global variable declarations so I'm kind confused why its not being passed along.  Should I have it declared as an extern in the header?

Comment: @ChefFlambe Show the exact error message. If you have only one compilation unit then the array can be defined in the header.

Comment: @ChefFlambe If there are several compilation units then you should declare the array with the specifier extern in the header and define it in a module,

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error  '_cylinder_types' undeclared (first use in this function) V4_1 C:\Users\sysadmin\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\projectBuilds\V4_11_29_working\V4_1\lcd.c 111

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. does not yet compile because it is missing, amongst other things, the include statements for the header files.
2. demonstrates how to initialize the array when it is declared, rather than via a series of assignment statements.
3. properly declares the array as an array of pointers to strings
4. uses an indent width of 4 spaces as that is very readable
5. separates code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line
6. does not name the array, starting with `_` as such names are 'reserved' of the OS
7. allows the compiler to determine the size of the array
8. uses the 'preprocessor' operator 'sizeof' to calculate the second parameter of the `for()` statement.
9. breaks the `for()` statement so it does not runoff the right edge of the page
10. uses appropriate horizontal spacing, inside parens, after semicolons, after commas, etc for readability
11. replaces the incorrect `lcd_write( 0 );` (which should be passed a character, not a integer) with `lcd_write( '0' );`

and now, the proposed code:

```
char *cylinder_types[] =
{
    "Blk",
    "Wht",
    "Stl",
    "Alu",
    "Err"
};


int main( void )
{
    for(int i=0;
        i < sizeof( cylinder_types ) / sizeof( char * );
        i++ )
    {
        lcd_write( '0' );
        lcd_position( lcd_TopLine, 1 );
        lcd_string( "SORTED:" );
        lcd_string( cylinder_types[i] );
        lcd_write( ':' );
        lcd_write_Num_8( drop_number[i] );

        lcd_position( lcd_BotLine, 1 );
        lcd_string( "UNSORTED:" );
        lcd_string( cylinder_types[i] );
        lcd_write( ':' );
        lcd_write_Num_8( queued_number[i] );

        mTimer( 5000 );
    }
}
```